# expression evaluation for large data set in angular js.ways to speed up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am having a large dataset which is presented in a table ! the table has 1000 rows with 60 columns.in which 24 columns are d3 graph.i am using infinite scroll it appends 30 rows on scroll to bottom.the dynamic directive compiles and returns html. the table becomes slow due to heavy dom(svg elements). How do i speed up!

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="row-2-td-2-table">
<tr ng-repeat="item in dataset"  data-code="{{item.code}}"  ng-class="{'firstTr' : $index == 0}" emit-when="{event: 'allRendered', condition: $last}">
    <td ng-repeat="key in orderedkeys" >
        <div dynamic="Val_Helper(key,item[key])" class=" {{key}} tablechild"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js function:(which gets fired many times due to two way binding)

```
$scope.Val_Helper = function(key,value)
{
 if(key=="firstkey")
        return generategraph1(value);
 if(key=="secondkey")
        return generategraph2(value);
 .
 .
 .
 if(key=="sixteenthdkey")
 .... return generate16graph(value);
return value;
}
```